# How to save last three entries

Tags: python, file

I'm attempting to save the amount of times a users name appears and once that count reaches 3, it'll overwrite a score on a file instead of adding it.

For example;

```
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:1
 Jarrod:2
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:1
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
 Jarrod:0
```

Instead, it'll show

```
Jarrod:0
Jarrod:0
Jarrod:0
```

The last three scores.

```
if classs == "1":
    textfile = open("Class1.txt", "a")
    textfile.write(name.title()+ ':' + str(score) + "\n")
    textfile.close()

with open("Class1.txt") as f:
    entrylist = []
    for line in f:
        column = line.split(":")
        namefile = column[0]
        scores = int(column[1].strip())
        entrylist.append(namefile)

    namecount = []
    for word in entrylist:
        if word not in namecount:
            namecount += [word]
    word_count = []
    for word in namecount:
            word_count += [float(entrylist.count(word))]
    for i in range(len(namecount)):
        print(namecount[i] + ":" + str(word_count[i]))
```

Here i've managed to add the users name to `namecount`, which is then added to `word_count` where the number of times it appears is kept

How do I isolate the number count for the certain name and then overwrite that users lastest score?

Comment: can you explain more about your logic here?

Comment: @haifzhan I made a quiz, when a user does the quiz it saves his score to a txt file; Name:score. I want to make it so once the user has done the quiz X amount of times, instead of adding the new scores it replaces the old ones. So the user never has more entries than X in the text file.

Comment: if so, why your output sample show `Jarrod:0` 3 times?

Comment: @haifzhan those are the last three scores . . .

Comment: @haifzhan It shows Jarrod:0 3 times because they are the lastest scores in the list above. Not the best example, my bad. But for the last 3 attempts the user "jarrod" got the score "0". So instead of showing the previous scores he got, it just shows the last 3 scores he got, which was three 0's

Comment: @JJA, please fix the indentation under the `if` statement at the top of your code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `collections.deque` object. The [constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) lets you limit the total size of the list.

I've not entirely followed how your code works, but I think a `dict` or `collections.defaultdict` would also be a better choice if there are multiple users in one file. I'm not sure if that's a requirement of your code or not.

Something more like this: (not tested)

```
import collections

def new3ElementDeque():
   return collections.deque([], 3)

userTop3 = collections.defaultdict(new3ElementDeque)

with open("Class1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        user, score = line.split(':')
        userTop3[user].append(score)
```

That way each user has their own `deque` that only ever stores up to three elements. You can then just write those out to separate files.

Comment: Thanks. I know my list method wasn't the most efficent, but due to my knowledge of python (which isn't alot) it was the easiest choice. I'll read around the import collections.